# Laravel database queuing jobs attempts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, queue

I implemented a laravel queue with the database driver, in an Ubuntu 14.04 server. I execute this code

```
php /path to app/artisan queue:listen --tries=3 --env=local
```

It says tries=3. But when I see the jobs table I see jobs with 22 attempts, how is this possible? it should try 3 times and then add it to failed_jobs table.

Also, what does reserved_at means in the jobs table?.

Thank you

Here is the job that, by the way, it works perfectly

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use App\Notifiers\Im_Notification;
use App\Notifiers\Notification;
use App\Notifiers\Mail_Notification;
use App\Reservation;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class NotifyPlaceReservationStatus extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected $notification;
protected $reservation;
protected $info_changed;

public function __construct(Notification $notification,Reservation $reservation)
{
    $this->reservation = $reservation;
    $this->notification = $notification;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $this->notification->notifyPlaceReservationStatus($this->reservation);
}

public function failed()
{
    error_log('Job failed');
}
}
```

Comment: You should show the job it self. The problem might lie there.

Comment: Ok, I put it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you provide the number of tries in the CLI, Laravel worker is going to apply the tries limit only for those jobs currently in the queue (or in your unexecuted job table if you prefer). In order to make every execution of a job have a try limit, you should put a public $tries attribute in your Job class as stated in the Laravel documentation on [Dispatching Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout) (for Laravel 5.4)

```
public $tries = 3;
protected $notification;
protected $reservation;
protected $info_changed;
```